# What's the point of a Client ID in implicit Grant?

Tags: oauth-2.0

so in Oauth2, what's the point of using a Client ID if you want to do an implicit grant? I mean, Client ID and Client secret are preventions against data and quota theft, but by Stealing someone's ClientID from an authorization URL, you can simply run an application, while pretending to be someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Authorization Server always needs to receive a client id so that it can look up client specific settings, which might include token lifetimes and which scopes that app allows.

Tokens are returned only on an HTTPS url that you own, so that only you can get tokens for that client id:

- https:/my company.com/myapp

Interestingly the point you raise is possibly a risk when the redirect URI is not an https url, as can be the case for desktop and mobile apps.